# redirect http to https making a problem in subdirectory as 404 - Not found

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

htaccess in root folder

```
#<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#RewriteEngine On
#Uncomment these two lines If you want to redirect http to https
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
#RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
#</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^https://3pmix.com/ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

htaccess in sub folder

```
RewriteRule ^classes/.*$ - [F,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} config.php|db.php|functions.php [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

directory structure through images

[image]

Comment: website linke https://3pmix.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite base was missing that is why was not finding the root url of the website

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, please try following Rules file. Also make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

Have your root htaccess Rule file like as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^3pmix\.com [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
</IfModule>
```

And have your sub directory htaccess Rules file as follows:

```
RewriteOptions InheritBefore
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^classes - [NC,F,L]
RewriteRule (?:config\.php|db\.php|functions\.php) - [NC,F,L]
```

I have also fixed flags and regex in your htaccess files.

Comment: @mudasirabbasturi, sorry I didn't get it, please try your Rules file likes shown above once and let me know if this is helpful, cheers.

Comment: problem is not solved again with modification

Comment: @mudasirabbasturi, these rules should work fine, could you please do mention which sample url you are using?